# Scripting my bank

Tags: scripting, banking

I want to write scripts which access my internet banking data. Mostly read-only stuff for drawing graphs and sending alerts and so on.

But I don't want to write my internet banking login details in plaintext in a script.

How do I resolve this dilemma?

I'd like to be able to run things from cronjobs/periodically if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having thought about it for a while, it seems like the best answer is to get a bank which can email you when transactions occur. Then, parse those emails.

Not the ideal solution, but the only one that is both likely (my bank will at least email me when transactions > $20 happen) and safe (if that script breaks, the worst it can do is provide me with false information).

Answer (score 2):

You should check [boobank](http://weboob.org/applications/boobank), this is a web site **scraper** that already support a wide range of bank (hum, mostly French banks, I figure). But adding your module would be a great contribution and you don't have the hassle of making all the command line stuff.

For the other part of your question, boobank will store your password in `~/.config/weboob/backends`, in a file, cleartext, only readable by you. This might not be enough for you. But this is surely much better than providing the password on the command line!

Comment: The backends file can also prompt you, or call a command (typically a password manager), to get the password. Otherwise, there is also the WebNip class which allows you to build the backends yourself, i.e. without the backends plain-text file.

Comment: To do that, put `password = \`mycommand_to_get_passwd\`` in _backends_.

Answer (score 1):

Make your script accept command line arguments for username and password and use the passed in values.

Comment: Ideally, the script would be running from a cron job.

Comment: Also, then my uname/pword show up in my bash history, top, ps, they hang around in my RAM, are visible in scrollback, etc. etc.

Answer (score 1):

While a good suggestion from *Oded*, the only problem lies when supplying command-line arguments to a program/script, they will show up in top(1) and ps(1) while the process is running. Granted, this is probably going to be used on your personal computer, where you are the only user logged on, but on multi-user systems, this would be rather risky.

Comment: It probably will be running from a multiuser system. These are important concerns.

Comment: My suggestion, as far as the username/password thing go - my suggestion would be to have a quick, first-time wizard that takes the user's information, hashes it (using MD5 or SHA256) and prompts them for their username and password, every time they run the script. This way, you are not comparing raw data (you are comparing the hashes) and for some extra padding, make sure the script turns off read flags for everyone but the owner ("chmod 400 .bankscriptrc").

Comment: Unfortunately that's not compatible with me hitting my bank's web interface from a cron job.

Answer (score -2):

Use some two way encryption algorithm like AES or DES.